# How do I add a directory and all it files into git

Tags: git

I have a directory called admin and I would like to add all the files contained in the admin directory but "git add admin" does not seem to add all my files. How do I add all the files in my directory to git? I have made not commits so far and I have done "git init" in admins parent directory

Comment: Do you already have a git repo? did you commit? push? Are some of your files added? Do you have a .gitignore? You'll need to provide more info.

Comment: What *does* `git add admin` do? Saying what it doesn’t do isn’t particularly helpful.

Comment: git add is supposed to stage your file for a commit

Comment: in this case I am trying to stage all files in my directory for a commit

Comment: Did you do `git status` and see that it's not staged?

Comment: I did git status but it only showed admin, it did not show any files contained in admin

Comment: `git add --all` ?

Comment: git add --all just adds the name of the directory

Comment: Go to directory and fire git add *

Answer (score 0):

As @ivo said, you can may a .gitignore file. Try removing the admin folder from it. If that does not work or you don't have a .gitignore you can use one of the following list of commands.
1.

```
git add admin
cd admin
git add $(ls)
git commit
```

2.

```
git add admin
git add admin/*
git commit
```

3.

```
git add -a # add all files
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems to be:

```
Parent
   Admin
```

And you've run `git init` in Parent, so all your git commands will be run in parent.

I would enable color coding in git first, as it makes status a little easier to read.

In the terminal, cd into Parent and type:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

Then.

```
git status
```

This will show you all the files under git's purview and their status. If you've enabled color, you'll see a list of files - mostly in the /admin/ path colored red, meaning they haven't been added, or staged as it's referred to in git.

Type:

```
git add *
```

This will add all of the files to git and stage them - they haven't been committed, just gathered up.

Type:

```
git commit -m "Some commit message that describes what this version is"
```

The files are now committed to the local repository

If you're hosting the repo on Github, and want to commit the files there, type:

```
git push origin master
```

This will push your commits to the master branch of the Github repo.

If you aren't using Github and you'd like to, there's very good documentation there to help setup a public or private repo, and commit your files to it.